# SQL Server : how to transpose rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In T-SQL I am trying to transpose the values of some rows into columns.
The initial table:

```
Project | Machine | Value
-------------------------
A   X   100
A   Y   99
A   Z   98
A   W   97
B   X   97
B   Y   96
B   W   95
C   X   95
C   Z   94
```

The result I'd like to have:

```
Project     MX  MY  MZ  MW
-----------------------------
A           100 99  98  97
B            97 96   0  95
C            95  0  94   0
```

I have created test code:

```
CREATE TABLE Company (project char(1), machine char(1), cost int)
GO

INSERT INTO Company 
VALUES ('A', 'X', 100), ('A', 'Y', 99), ('A', 'Z', 98),
       ('A', 'W', 97), ('B', 'X', 97), ('B', 'Y', 96),
       ('B', 'W', 95), ('C', 'X', 95), ('C', 'Z', 94);
```

My pivot query:

```
SELECT
    project, 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'W'
FROM
    (SELECT 
         project, machine, cost 
     FROM 
         Company) p
PIVOT
    (MAX(cost)
        FOR machine IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z', 'W') AS  pvt
```

I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near ''X''

Is my pivot query wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `PIVOT ( MAX(cost) FOR machine IN ([X], [Y], [Z], [W]) AS pvt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a limited machines, then i would do conditional aggregation instead of `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT Project,
       MAX(CASE WHEN machine = 'X' THEN cost END) AS MX,
       MAX(CASE WHEN machine = 'Y' THEN cost END) AS MY,
       MAX(CASE WHEN machine = 'Z' THEN cost END) AS MZ,
       MAX(CASE WHEN machine = 'W' THEN cost END) AS MW
FROM Company c
GROUP BY Project;
```

If you want to go with `PIVOT`, then i would fix the syntax error with missing closing parenthesis :

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT project, machine, cost 
      FROM Company 
     ) AS p PIVOT
     (MAX(cost)
      FOR machine IN ([X], [Y], [Z], [W]) 
     ) AS pvt;
```

Note :

- Don't use single quote as column name use square brackets instead.